# PHP.ini causes Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in/sys/index.php on line 19

Tags: php, mysqli

this script works fine on Local Host and Other free Hosting  but not  on "host Gator "it should be " PHP.ini " Any Help !?!?

### function.php

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
function consql($con){
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","BDusername","DBPassWord","DB") or die( mysqli_error($con));}
?>
```

### index.php

line #1 "Very top "

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
require_once"inc/function.php";
consql($con);
?>
```

### line#12

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("location:users.php");
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $result=mysqli_query("select user_id,password from user_login where name='$_POST[username]'")     or die(mysqli_error($con)); // ** line # 19 ** //
        $n=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($n['password']!=$_POST['userpassword'])
        {
          echo "user name or password wrong";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "you loged in as $_POST[username]";
          $_SESSION['user']=$n['user_id'];
          header("location:users.php");
        }
    }
    else
```

I'm new to mysqli and looked up here for same error but didn't get the point on most of them.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: Make sure your username and password are correct on your server.

Comment: @Enijar  connected  and my hosting company checked twice

Comment: Now Its something about Hosting  or " PHP.ini "  ANy Help !?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
function consql(&$con){
  $con=mysqli_connect("host","BDusername","DBPassWord","DB") or die( mysqli_error($con));
}
```

So this is call by reference and $con can use at any page once you call the function

Or use `global $con;` before the connection line

Answer (score -2):

**function.php**

```
function consql()
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","BDusername","DBPassWord","DB") or die( mysqli_error($con));
    return $con;
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once"inc/function.php";
$con = consql();
```

explanation :
why no error appears in your localhost‌? is it a PHP.ini problem ?

maybe errors are hidden on your localhost or mysqli_query runs with no problem there.
but there is a problem on your host, such as connection problem, missing or broken database table or etc...
base on your code, when no error occurs, mysqli_error() wont run and you dont get error

Comment: "have Made it and Not Works too"

Comment: make sure $con variable isnt used and filled with other values before line 19

Comment: its Works on another Free Hosting !! same coding  even without " Return "  and Automatically  Redirected to user.php "header("location:users.php"); "

Comment: most hosting providers hide errors on they servers for security reasons, if you just want to ignore this error put error_reporting(0) at top of your index.php, but I recommand find the error.

Comment: you right , also i'm looking  and try to find different between php.ini on both public hosting because i want to fix it not hide it

Comment: make sure table user_login imported in new server.